# toggle function doesnt work on server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a webpage with a submenu that appears when you click on the main menu. At the same time I wanted to include a transparent background that covers the whole page when the submenu is activated so that it stands out from the background page.

Up until this point everything seems fine, I've tried it in the Dreamweaver preview and it functions correctly. The problem occurs when I upload it to the server. The menu works fine but the transparent background doesn't appear.

This is the website www.whitedogstudio.org and as you will see when you open the menu a transparent background should appear to make the menu more visible.

this is the website: http://www.whitedogstudio.org/

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".menu").on("click", function(){
        deactivateAll(this);
        toggle(this);

    });

    function deactivateAll(current) {
        $( "li" ).each(function( index, elem ){
            if (elem != current && $(elem).hasClass("active")) {
                toggle(elem);
            }
        });
    }

    function toggle(elem) {
        $(elem).find("ul").toggle ("fast","linear");
        $( "#transparencia" ).toggle();
        $(elem).toggleClass("active");

     }
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: I get `others/fondo.png 404 (Not Found)`. Path should be "[OTHERS/](http://www.whitedogstudio.org/OTHERS/fondo.png)" not "[others/](http://www.whitedogstudio.org/others/fondo.png)".

Comment: NEVER trust Dreamweaver for previews. Only use real browsers.

Comment: can you post HTML? And, preferrably, post it all together on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?